# Cannot repair grub2 menu using boot-repair

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

I have a multi boot setup on my Thinkpad P43s laptop with windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. Everything has worked fine until I changed some Thunderbolt 3 configuration in BIOS to try a fix a well know problem with my Lenovo Thunderbolt Gen 2 dock.

But after applying those changes my machine now boots directly into windows and skips the grub2 menu.

I have found

https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

but when I go through those steps from a Live Ubuntu 20.4 USB disk I get this message

```
Please create a ESP partition (FAT32, 100MB~250MB, start of the disk, boot flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.
```

based on some other post I have found I have tried to disable secure boot in BIOS but that does not help, I have generated this log file:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4j93dYv3Hv/

From the Live USB I get:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             20G     0   20G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G  2.0M  3.9G   1% /run
/dev/sda1        15G  2.6G   12G  19% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      2.0G  2.0G     0 100% /rofs
/cow             20G  592M   19G   3% /
tmpfs            20G   62M   20G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            20G     0   20G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            20G  580K   20G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           3.9G   72K  3.9G   1% /run/user/999
/dev/loop1       28M   28M     0 100% /snap/snapd/7264
/dev/loop2       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop3      241M  241M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24
/dev/loop4       63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop5       50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/433
```

So it seems it cannot see my Ubuntu partition.

Any suggestions

Comment: What changes did you do to your Bios settings?

Comment: I tried to disable the Thunderbolt security and also enable Thunderbolt BIOS assist mode (its recommended if you run linux) . Apparently the effect of changing Thunderbolt configuration in BIOS has the downside effect of wiping grub2 boot menu - not really something I would have thought was so tightly connected

Comment: @u123 If you change the BIOS settings back, does it go back to normal?  I know you want to update your BIOS settings, but it's also helpful to know whether making that change was permanent or not.

Comment: As for the Live USB, not seeing it at boot-up is not unusual because they are not mounted by default.  You're supposed to mount them one-by-one and repair them.  Can you use the Disks tool or `gparted` to see if they allow you to mount them?  (You can also find and mount them on the command-line.)

Comment: I tried to revert my BIOS settings to default but grub2 menu is still wiped - why would changing Thunderbolt 3 settings in BIOS ever destroy the grub2 menu??